# Best practice for editing MVC3 auto generated code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012, ef-database-first

Im sorry if this is in the wrong place, however I think it is.

So I when creating an MVC3 internet application I used a database first method and my classes were generated for me. I am new to MVC3 and fairly new to c# and visual studio although I do have a little experience.

The auto-generated code warns that editing may cause unexpected results and the changes will be removed if the code is regenerated. As I understand it that means changes to the database, rerunning the tt files or updating the model.

However is it ok practice to edit it, and just keep a track of changes incase i need to regenerate, or is there a better way to go about it?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The classes generated should be `partial` classes so you should be able to externally manage enhancements by making your own `partial` class with the same namespace and name.

Comment: +1 "partial" keyword is the right way, how to manage autogenerated and customized code together.

Comment: Thank you, will read up on partial classes and how to put them together. Will accept when it lets me. :)

Comment: So if I have a public 'partial class pagetest' in a class file called pages.cs and the auto generated class page is called news_page but also called 'partial class pagetest'will this work? they are both in model and both under the same namespace project.Models. However the auto-generated partial class is in the .edmx file. does the other half of the partial class need to be moved in there as well?

Comment: As long as the generated class and your custom class share the same `namespace` and name. In your example you would want to name your custom class `news_page`.

Answer (score 1):

In the model first approach, using the default code generation strategy on you `EDMX` file, the classes generated for you `DbContext` and `Entity` classes are all partial classes.

So, depending on your type of changes, if you want to extend these generated classes, just create a new partial class with you custom code in it.  Your partial's will not be overwritten by the code generator.